# BASH =~ contains substring: "+" or a regex character behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, escaping

Curious to know why the following is not working for character: **+**

Characters **"\"**, **"("** and **"*"** makes sense i.e. ***** will expand to folders/files in current directory (during command line shell expansion) and similarly **\** and **(** will expect closing character to work but my understanding was **"+"** should have worked like **"-"** did.

**PS**: I know putting double quotes i.e. "${o}" in the IF statement, will work for all characters in my test case below. Using \${o} in IF statement  with or without double quote will fail all the checks.

```
$ for o in - + \` ~ \~ , _ = / \\ ! @ \# $ \$ % ^ \& \* \( \); do a="a${o}b${o}c";if [[ $a =~ ${o} ]]; then echo "${o} exists in $a and =~ works"; else echo -e "\ncharacter ${o} doesn't work with =~\n"; fi; done
- exists in a-b-c and =~ works

character + doesn't work with =~

` exists in a`b`c and =~ works
/home/ubuntu exists in a/home/ubuntub/home/ubuntuc and =~ works
~ exists in a~b~c and =~ works
, exists in a,b,c and =~ works
_ exists in a_b_c and =~ works
= exists in a=b=c and =~ works
/ exists in a/b/c and =~ works

character \ doesn't work with =~

! exists in a!b!c and =~ works
@ exists in a@b@c and =~ works
# exists in a#b#c and =~ works
$ exists in a$b$c and =~ works
$ exists in a$b$c and =~ works
% exists in a%b%c and =~ works
^ exists in a^b^c and =~ works
& exists in a&b&c and =~ works

character * doesn't work with =~


character ( doesn't work with =~

) exists in a)b)c and =~ works
```

Comment: No, `*` isn't expanding to a list of files -- in regex, it means "zero-or-more of the preceding token".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy correct, I meant for the "for" statement.

Comment: ...but you're escaping it, as `\*`, for the `for` statement, so it's not doing any such replacement there.

Comment: BTW, `^` doesn't work the way you think it does. `[[ hello =~ ^ ]]` is true, even though `hello` has no `^` in it, because `^` is regex-speak for "beginning of line". Likewise, `$` for end-of-line.

Comment: Agree. I escaped it. Good to know that with =~ + ? and * works like regex patterns. I'm losing my skills :). It would be interesting to know if without using " double quotes if I can make + or ? character work i.e. ${o}${o} in the IF statement as it as ++ or ?? where the first character + will be the litteral and second will work as regex + or ? or *.

Comment: Why would you want an ugly hack, instead of wanting to do the Right Thing? (In this case, the Right Thing is double quotes).

Comment: BTW, it's not just "like" regex patterns -- these really *are* regex patterns; they're evaluated by the standard C library's `regcomp()` and `regexec()` functions (with the `REG_EXTENDED` flag), meaning that extensions to ERE your operating system makes available (without requiring `REG_ENHANCED`) will be applied.

Comment: Found an old script and was curious why they didn't use " quotes. Luckily it was checking for working characters so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental misunderstanding behind this question is that `=~` is a substring-search operator. **It is not**.

The right-hand side of `=~` is evaluated as a POSIX ERE expression. `=~` is thus a regex-matching operator, which happens to be frequently used for searches when the right-hand side is quoted to make its contents literal (or when this string is known to match only itself when interpreted as an ERE).

---

`+`, in regex, means "1-or-more of the preceding token" -- just as `*` means "0-or-more of the preceding token".

Thus, either `[[ $foo =~ + ]]` or `[[ $foo =~ * ]]` makes no sense, because these are checking for zero-or-more of a preceding token *that doesn't exist at all*.

Similarly, `(` and `)` have meaning in ERE as the beginning and end of a match group, so when they're given bare (unescaped/unquoted), they result in an invalid regex.

If you quote the expansion, by contrast, all characters contained will be treated as literal, rather than being treated as regular expression metacharacters, thus resulting in the presumably-intended behavior.

---

If you want to check whether a literal character is contained in a string, either quote it -- `[[ $foo =~ "$o" ]]` -- or use a glob-style pattern: `[[ $foo = *"$o"* ]]`